# Methodology to distinguish single and double exponential distribution

Tags: distributions, maximum-likelihood, exponential-distribution

I have a set of n data points $x = [x_1, x_2,...,x_n]$ that follow an [exponential distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution) or a double exponential distribution (two different $\lambda$ parameters).

In order to check which distribution works better, I did Maximum Likelihood Estimation (mle) for each of the 2 distribuions. For monoexponential, I followed this [method](https://www.statlect.com/fundamentals-of-statistics/exponential-distribution-maximum-likelihood), whereas for the double exponential I used this [one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/421084/217516).

The problem is I don't know whether `x` follows a mono or double exponential distribution. Which statistical criteria would be more suited to make a decision?

The following code in Python generates some data `x` that follows a biexponential distribution with 2:1 relative weights:

```
import numpy as np
x2 = np.random.exponential(scale=2, size=500)
x5 = np.random.exponential(scale=5, size=1000)
x = np.concatenate([x2, x5])
```

Comment: You could estimate both models with mle and then calculate the aic.

Comment: 1. That's not how you simulate from a double exponential; rather than have a fixed number each side of the mode, you should be fixing the probabilities; the proportions should vary. 2. There is a "Fourier transform for distributions".

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Thanks, actually I had run some tests using bic, the retults were a bit meh, maybe my sample was not large enough. I'll try using aic too.

Comment: @Glen_b *That's not how you simulate from a double exponential*. Do you mean the 1st comment or the method I [linked](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/419268/efficiently-estimate-double-exponential-parameters-from-time-series/421084#421084)?

Comment: I'm talking about the code. Whatever led you to do the two sides in fixed proportion is problematic